# R Apexcharter: Formatting tooltip

Tags: r, plot, format, label, apexcharts

I created an areaRange plot with the dreamRs apexcharter package and have a few issues formatting the hoverlabel/tooltip.
This is my sample code:

First, I installed the dreamRs apexcharter version using this:

```
#install.packages("remotes")
#remotes::install_github("dreamRs/apexcharter")
```

And then I loaded the following packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(apexcharter)
```

The apexcharter version I have now is: apexcharter_0.3.1.9200

This is my example data:

```
test_data <- data.frame(seq(as.POSIXct('2022/09/04 22:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2022/09/08 10:00:00'), by="hour"))

test_data$MIN <- runif(n = 85, min = 70, max = 100)
test_data$MEDIAN <- runif(n = 85, min = 100, max = 120)
test_data$MAX <- runif(n = 85, min = 120, max = 150)

colnames(test_data) <- c("Date", "MIN", "MEDIAN", "MAX")
```

And this is my plot so far:

```
axc_plot <- apex(data = test_data, # plot the area range
                 mapping = aes(x = test_data[20:60,]$Date, 
                               ymin = test_data[20:60,]$MIN, 
                               ymax = rev(test_data[20:60,]$MAX)), 
                 type = "rangeArea", 
                 serie_name = "Vertrauensbereich") %>% 
  add_line(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = MEDIAN), # add the line
           type = "line", 
           serie_name = "Median") %>% 
  ax_colors("lightblue", "red") %>% # why is the line not red?
  ax_labs(x = "Zeit [h]", 
          y = "Q [m³/s]") %>%
  ax_tooltip(enabled = T, 
             shared = T, # I want it shared but it's not
             x = list(format = "dd.MM. HH:mm"), # changes grey hoverlabel at the bottom -> works
             y = list(formatter = JS("function(seriesName) {return seriesName;}"), # instead of the time I want it to say "Median" and "Vertrauensbereich"
                      title = list(formatter = JS("function(test_data$Date) {return test_data$Date;}")))) # the title of the hoverlabel should be the time in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  
axc_plot
```

Here's how it looks:

[rangeArea Plot with tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DAV0.png)

As you can see the data in the tooltip is not displayed very well, so I want to format it using `ax_tooltip` but that hasn't worked very well so far. I found out that using `x =` will change the grey hoverlabel at the bottom of the plot and `y =` changes the label that runs along with the lines (which is the one I want to change). I tried to make a custom tooltip using `formatter =` but I don't really know how to work with it because all examples I see are made with Java Script and I don't know how to implement that in R. In `ax_tooltip(y = ...)` you can see how I tried to change the format using `JS()` because I saw it once somewhere (can't find the link anymore sadly) but I'm pretty sure that's not the way to do it as it doesn't change anything.

In the end, I'd like to achieve a tooltip that looks something like this with the Date at the top (as title) in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" if possible and then the series names with the corresponding values and hopefully also with the unit m³/s:

[apex desired tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euOpv.png)

Thanks in advance for any answers. I'm looking forward to hearing your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this question on GitHub where **pvictor** solved my problem perfectly. This is what they answered and what works for me:

```
library(htmltools)

test_data <- data.frame(seq(as.POSIXct('2022/09/04 22:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2022/09/08 10:00:00'), by="hour"))
test_data$MIN <- runif(n = 85, min = 70, max = 100)
test_data$MEDIAN <- runif(n = 85, min = 100, max = 120)
test_data$MAX <- runif(n = 85, min = 120, max = 150)
colnames(test_data) <- c("Date", "MIN", "MEDIAN", "MAX")

# explicit NA if not used in area range
test_data$MIN[-c(20:60)] <- NA
test_data$MAX[-c(20:60)] <- NA

# Construct tooltip with HTML tags
test_data$tooltip <- unlist(lapply(
  X = seq_len(nrow(test_data)),
  FUN = function(i) {
    d <- test_data[i, ]
    doRenderTags(tags$div(
      style = css(padding = "5px 10px;", border = "1px solid #FFF", borderRadius = "5px"),
      format(d$Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"),
      tags$br(),
      tags$span("Q Median:", tags$b(round(d$MEDIAN), "m\u00b3/s")),
      if (!is.na(d$MIN)) {
        tagList(
          tags$br(),
          tags$span("Vertrauensbereich:", tags$b(round(d$MIN), "m\u00b3/s -", round(d$MAX), "m\u00b3/s"))
        )
      }
    ))
  }
))

axc_plot <- apex(
  data = test_data[20:60, ], # plot the area range
  mapping = aes(
    x = Date, 
    ymin = MIN, 
    ymax = rev(MAX),
    tooltip = tooltip # variable containing the HTML tooltip
  ), 
  type = "rangeArea", 
  serie_name = "Vertrauensbereich"
) %>% 
  add_line(
    data = test_data,
    mapping = aes(x = Date, y = MEDIAN, tooltip = tooltip), # use same tooltip variable
    type = "line", 
    serie_name = "Median"
  ) %>% 
  ax_colors(c("lightblue", "#FF0000")) %>% # use HEX code instaed of name
  ax_theme(mode = "dark") %>%
  ax_labs(
    x = "Zeit [h]", 
    y = "Q [m³/s]"
  ) %>% 
  ax_tooltip(
    # Custom tooltip: retrieve the HTML tooltip defined in data
    custom = JS(
      "function({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {",
      "var tooltip = w.config.series[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex].tooltip;",
      "return typeof tooltip == 'undefined' ? null : tooltip;",
      "}"
    )
  )

axc_plot
```

You can find the GitHub entry here: https://github.com/dreamRs/apexcharter/issues/62